Film where wife has apparently just died, but technology allows husband to communicate with her for a few days after death
I watched the film online. It was probably made between 2000 and 2022.
The husband works alone in a remote research facility accessed by a bridge. He communicates with his apparently recently deceased wife, who is elsewhere, inside a large black machine which allows the living to communicate with the dead, by preserving some form of consciousness, for just a few days after death.
The research facility is eventually attacked and damaged by a paramilitary force. There is a big twist at the end when it is revealed it was the husband who had actually died, not the wife. He is inside the black machine and everything that has occurred was in his imagination.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?

This is Archive (2020). The ending is largely as you've described.

J2, confronted with the realization that she will never be anything
more or better than she already is, destroys herself by walking into a
lake. Archive recovers the robot, and threaten to sue George's
company. When she learns that George has been building robots, his
boss fires him. He makes the final call to his wife on the Archive
machine, and ends the call saying "see you soon." J3 overhears this
and realizes that he intends to overwrite her consciousness with that
of his wife. Though initially angry and afraid, she accepts her fate.
The upload is completed as security storms George's lab.
At this point, any sign of the security team suddenly evaporates, and
all is calm. The Archive starts ringing with an incoming call from
Jules. J3 implores him not to answer, but George does and speaks to
Jules, also hearing a child's voice on the line which is revealed to
be that of his daughter. George was the one who died in the accident,
while Jules survived and is now raising their daughter in the real
world, and the ordeal he went through was a simulation within his own
Archive, which has finally expired. With his Archive expired, it has
been prepared for burial at his official funeral. Jules and their
daughter say their final goodbyes and leave.





Yes. Archive is the film I was thinking of.

@NickDavies - Don't forget to mark this as 'accepted' and upvote it :-)
